# WIndows - manifest based ETW provider issue

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, trace, etw

I have a C/C++ app where I want to use a manifest based ETW solution. I have issues when using tools that open a generated *.etl (like default one on Windows, or any other) in that I cannot see the specific details of my events (defined templates in manifest)

How do I register the manifest to the system and specify it to well known ETW consumers tools to show that info ?

I did what was mentioned in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570690/Application-Analysis-with-Event-Tracing-for-Window

```
mc FirstETW.man //included generated *.rc in project
mc -um FirstETW.man //to generate C files that I've used in the ETW provider executable
rc FirstETW.rc // not sure of this .Already included the generated *.rc script from previous step in the visual studio project
```

Also registered the manifest with:

```
wevtutil.exe im FirstETW.man  //installs the provider
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was related to the fact that in the manifest it was specified a provider messageFileName that was different than the location of the actual binary that included the resources(strings) needed by the ETW consumers (e.g. Event Log or other tools).

Also when expecting to see logs in Event Viewer make sure that you enable in Event Viewer the provider for Analytics or Debug Channel type.